# ¿Por qué en C, el desplazamiento de bits de un elemento de una array de enteros, me modifica el valor de otro elemento del array?

Tags: c

Este programa toma una cadena hexa, convierte los pares hexadecimales a enteros y los almacena en un array de enteros. Luego la segunda parte del código toma cada uno de esos enteros del array de enteros y calcula la Base64. El problemo lo estoy teniendo en la segunda parte del código cuando trabajo con desplazamientos de bits. Esta parte del codigo me altera el array de enteros o algunos de sus elementos, cuando no debería ser asi.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    if (argc != 2)
        return 0;

    int lengthArgvOne = strlen(argv[1]);

    /* Variables de control */
    unsigned short int i, j, k, moduleArgv;

    char *oneHexaArgvChar = argv[1];
    char *hexaCharset = "0123456789abcdef";
    char *base64Charset = "ABDCEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/";
    int decimalElements = (lengthArgvOne / 2);
    unsigned short int *boxOfNumbers = (unsigned short int*)malloc(decimalElements);

    if(((lengthArgvOne % 3) == 2) || ((lengthArgvOne % 3) == 1))
        moduleArgv = 1;
    else
        moduleArgv = 0;

    int base64Elements = (((lengthArgvOne / 3) * 4) + (moduleArgv * 4));
    unsigned char *decimalConverted = (unsigned char*)malloc(base64Elements);

    /* Cantidad de sextetos base64 para representar argv[1] */
    if (((lengthArgvOne % 3) == 2) || ((lengthArgvOne % 3 ) == 1))
        i = 1;
    else
        i = 0;

    struct {
        unsigned int eightBits : 0x8;     
        unsigned int sixBits   : 0x6;     
    } chunksOfByte; 
    /* ----------Procesamiento y control de datos de entrada argv[1].----------- */
    /* Conversión de Mayúsculas(A,B,C,D,E y F) a Minúsculas(a,b,c,d,e y f).  */
    /* Se corrobora que los caracteres en argv[1] sean hexa.*/
    /* Converción de hexa a decimal. Se almacena el decimal en boxOfNumbers*/
    for (i = 0, j = 0,k = 0; i < lengthArgvOne; i++) {
                 if ((*(oneHexaArgvChar + i) > 64) && (*(oneHexaArgvChar + i) < 71)) {
            *(oneHexaArgvChar + i) = (*(oneHexaArgvChar + i) + 32);
        }
        /*------------*/
        while(*(oneHexaArgvChar + i) != *(hexaCharset + j)){
            j++;
            if (j == 16)
                return 0;
        } 
        /*------------*/
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            chunksOfByte.eightBits = j << 4;
        } else {
            boxOfNumbers[k++] = (chunksOfByte.eightBits + j);
        }
        j = 0;
    }
    /* ------------------------------------------------------------------------ */
    for (i = 0; i < decimalElements; i++)
        printf("Elemento %d antes de converción a base64 : %d\n", i, boxOfNumbers[i]); 
    /* --------------------Converción de decimal a base64---------------------- */
    for (i = 0, j = 0, k = 0; i < decimalElements; i++) {
        printf("Elemento %d dentro del FOR de converción: %d\n", i, boxOfNumbers[i]); 
        if (j == 0) {
            decimalConverted[k++] = *(base64Charset + (boxOfNumbers[i] >> 2));
            chunksOfByte.sixBits = (boxOfNumbers[i] << 4);
            if (((decimalElements % 3) == 1) && (i == (decimalElements -1))) {
                decimalConverted[k++] = *(base64Charset + chunksOfByte.sixBits);
                decimalConverted[k++] = '=';
                decimalConverted[k] = '=';
            }
        }
        if (j == 1) {
             decimalConverted[k++] = *(base64Charset + (chunksOfByte.sixBits | (boxOfNumbers[i] >> 4)));
             chunksOfByte.sixBits = boxOfNumbers[i] << 2;
             if (((decimalElements % 3) == 2) && (i == (decimalElements - 1))) {
                 decimalConverted[k++] = *(base64Charset + chunksOfByte.sixBits);
                 decimalConverted[k] = '=';
             }
         }
         if (j == 2) {
             decimalConverted[k++] = *(base64Charset + (chunksOfByte.sixBits | (boxOfNumbers[i] >> 6)));
             chunksOfByte.sixBits = boxOfNumbers[i];
             decimalConverted[k++] = *(base64Charset + chunksOfByte.sixBits);
         }

         (j == 2) ? (j = 0) : j++;
     }

     printf("Base64: %s\n", decimalConverted);

     return 0;
}
```

Ejemplo de salida:

```
./limpio 49276d206b696c6c69
Elemento 0 antes de converción a base64 : 73
Elemento 1 antes de converción a base64 : 39
Elemento 2 antes de converción a base64 : 109
Elemento 3 antes de converción a base64 : 32
Elemento 4 antes de converción a base64 : 107
Elemento 5 antes de converción a base64 : 105
Elemento 6 antes de converción a base64 : 108
Elemento 7 antes de converción a base64 : 108
Elemento 8 antes de converción a base64 : 105 // ⬅️VALOR ORIGINAL
Elemento 0 dentro del FOR de converción: 73
Elemento 1 dentro del FOR de converción: 39
Elemento 2 dentro del FOR de converción: 109
Elemento 3 dentro del FOR de converción: 32
Elemento 4 dentro del FOR de converción: 107
Elemento 5 dentro del FOR de converción: 105
Elemento 6 dentro del FOR de converción: 108
Elemento 7 dentro del FOR de converción: 108
Elemento 8 dentro del FOR de converción: 21331 // ⬅️¿POR QUE ACA VALE ESTO??????????? VALOR ALTERADO
Base64: SSdtIGtpbG
```

Todas estas, son líneas de control, y como pueden ver el valor de boxOfNumbers[8] es disntinto.
¿Por que se altera el valor de boxOfNumbers[8]?

Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS i686 32bits
Compilado: **gcc -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -o test test.c**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

MacOS Sierra i5 64bits
Compilado: **gcc -g -Wall limpio.c**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si, funciona y creo que la pregunta esta mas que clara,**¿Por qué se cambia el valor de un elemento del array de tipo int al hacer desplazamientos de bits en sus elementos hermanos?**.

Comment: Hay cosas raras como `*(set_base64 + b_c.b_8);` y uso de `char *` en vez de `unsigned char`... debes hacer homogéneo todo el código y pensar que jugar con mezclas entre enteros, enteros cortos y caracteres con y sin signo puede acabar dándote dolores de cabeza. Piensa que, por ejemplo, las operaciones de desplazamiento de bits `>>` y `<<` funcionan de manera diferente con números sin signo que con signo. ¿Has probado un depurador para probar paso a paso la ejecución?

Comment: Acabo de compilarlo y no pasa las pruebas de `valgrind` sin parámetros, aunque con parámetros sí :/ voy a echarle un vistazo en profundidad con el depurador.

Comment: De verdad lo mandaría a leer `código limpio` de Robert Cecil Martin... parece código ofuscado. Si me tocara refactorizar esto, lo eliminaría completamente y empezaría de cero :P

Comment: Le da muchas vueltas a algo tan sencillo como sacar un carácter como mínimo por cada carácter de entrada e ir acumulando los dos bits para el siguiente... analiza todo completamente y de manera confusa usando sumas de punteros con enteros.. sin siquiera comentarios!! x( voy a retomar el tema, le echaré 5 minutos contados a depurar paso a paso para ver dónde se modifica tanto, pero aunque averigüe el motivo no voy a quedarme a hacer funcionar el código :/

Comment: La respuesta es igual de clara: **no se modifica nada al usar `<<` o `>>`**. Se crea un nuevo dato, resultado de la operación realizada. Por lo tanto, el fallo está en **como lo guardas en memoria** o en **como lo muestras**. Ya te lo han indicado en los comentarios, las mezclas de tipo suelen dar resultados *curiosos*: `signed`, `unsigned`, *anchos* distintos (`short` e `int`), ...

Comment: Soy nuevo en programación, gracias por los aportes. Tomo las criticas de como meramentes constructivas y como gran fuente de información. Ahora me pongo manos a la obra con la homogeneización del código. Tambien entiendo que se puede optmizar mejor. Debido a mi falta de experiencia, me concentre en hacerlo funcionar, y una vez funcionando, pensaba optimizarlo... pero me encontre con este contratiempo.

Comment: Creo que estás siguiendo un fantasma. He ejecutado tu código y he vigilado el estado de la variable y no cambia en ningún momento (sólo cuando se asigna al valer `z` 4, momento en el que se le asigna un valor que permanece inamovible hasta el final. Entonces me di cuenta que tu `printf` estaba generando texto sin los parámetros necesarios. Mira mi respuesta y comenta lo que veas oportuno.

Comment: Tu código no es reproducible. Ejecutando el código que tienes ahora mismo no consigo obtener la misma salida que das de ejemplo en tu pregunta. ¿Podrías actualizarla? ¿Podrías explicar un poco más a qué te refieres con "que se hace el lío"?

Comment: @Arie CwHat. Aca esta el código limpio y mejor codifcado.

Comment: @Dolmenes Acá esta el código mas limpio, mas legible y mejor codificado.

Comment: Ahora tu problema va de mal en peor, ahora ni tan siquiera pasa los tests de `valgrind`. Mira la última edición de mi respuesta.

Comment: Agregados los detalles y los cambios que he hecho en tu código.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema que sufres está en la siguiente línea:

```
printf("dec_val[%d] es: %d\n", dec_val[i]);
```

En ella tienes la necesidad de imprimir dos enteros, pero sólo pones uno, te falta el otro, por lo que la función `printf` te muestra esos valores tan extraños.

Deberías poner una de estas dos líneas:

```
printf("dec_val[4] es: %d\n", dec_val[4]);
printf("dec_val[%d] es: %d\n", i, dec_val[i]);
```

Con eso verás que ya te cambia. Poniendo ambas con el texto de entrada "49276d206b" me da la siguiente salida:

```
Cantidad de sextetos: 8
Decimal dec_val[0] = 73
Decimal dec_val[1] = 39
Decimal dec_val[2] = 109
Decimal dec_val[3] = 32
Decimal dec_val[4] = 107
Aca empieza la converción a base64
dec_val[4] es: 107
dec_val[0] es: 73
dec_val[4] es: 107
dec_val[1] es: 39
dec_val[4] es: 107
dec_val[2] es: 109
dec_val[4] es: 107
dec_val[3] es: 32
dec_val[4] es: 107
dec_val[4] es: 107
SSdtIGs=
```

Así que estabas persiguiendo un fantasma, el valor de `dec_val[4]` nunca había cambiado, era el valor de cada índice el que debería cambiar pero no lo hacía porque no estabas usando `printf` correctamente (estaba usando arbitrariamente un valor en la pila que no variaba).

---

**Actualizado con los datos de la última edición de la pregunta:**

Tu programa tiene diversos problemas de punteros. La salida de `valgrind` para tu entrada de prueba (`./test 49276d206b696c6c69`) lanza estos errores:

```
$ valgrind ./test 49276d206b696c6c69
==4076== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==4076== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==4076== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==4076== Command: ./test 49276d206b696c6c69
==4076== 
==4076== Invalid write of size 2
==4076==    at 0x4007D0: main (in ./test)
==4076==  Address 0x5203048 is 8 bytes inside a block of size 9 alloc'd
==4076==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4076==    by 0x400622: main (in ./test)
==4076== 
Elemento 0 antes de converción a base64 : 73
Elemento 1 antes de converción a base64 : 39
Elemento 2 antes de converción a base64 : 109
Elemento 3 antes de converción a base64 : 32
==4076== Invalid read of size 2
==4076==    at 0x400808: main (in ./test)
==4076==  Address 0x5203048 is 8 bytes inside a block of size 9 alloc'd
==4076==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4076==    by 0x400622: main (in ./test)
==4076== 
Elemento 4 antes de converción a base64 : 107
Elemento 5 antes de converción a base64 : 105
Elemento 6 antes de converción a base64 : 108
Elemento 7 antes de converción a base64 : 108
Elemento 8 antes de converción a base64 : 105
Elemento 0 dentro del FOR de converción: 73
Elemento 1 dentro del FOR de converción: 39
Elemento 2 dentro del FOR de converción: 109
Elemento 3 dentro del FOR de converción: 32
==4076== Invalid read of size 2
==4076==    at 0x40085D: main (in ./test)
==4076==  Address 0x5203048 is 8 bytes inside a block of size 9 alloc'd
==4076==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4076==    by 0x400622: main (in ./test)
==4076== 
Elemento 4 dentro del FOR de converción: 107
==4076== Invalid read of size 2
==4076==    at 0x4009A0: main (in ./test)
==4076==  Address 0x5203048 is 8 bytes inside a block of size 9 alloc'd
==4076==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4076==    by 0x400622: main (in ./test)
==4076== 
==4076== Invalid read of size 2
==4076==    at 0x4009CA: main (in ./test)
==4076==  Address 0x5203048 is 8 bytes inside a block of size 9 alloc'd
==4076==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4076==    by 0x400622: main (in ./test)
==4076== 
Elemento 5 dentro del FOR de converción: 105
==4076== Invalid read of size 2
==4076==    at 0x400A86: main (in ./test)
==4076==  Address 0x520304a is 1 bytes after a block of size 9 alloc'd
==4076==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4076==    by 0x400622: main (in ./test)
==4076== 
==4076== Invalid read of size 2
==4076==    at 0x400AB0: main (in ./test)
==4076==  Address 0x520304a is 1 bytes after a block of size 9 alloc'd
==4076==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4076==    by 0x400622: main (in ./test)
==4076== 
Elemento 6 dentro del FOR de converción: 108
==4076== Invalid read of size 2
==4076==    at 0x4008A7: main (in ./test)
==4076==  Address 0x520304c is 3 bytes after a block of size 9 alloc'd
==4076==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4076==    by 0x400622: main (in ./test)
==4076== 
==4076== Invalid read of size 2
==4076==    at 0x4008CC: main (in ./test)
==4076==  Address 0x520304c is 3 bytes after a block of size 9 alloc'd
==4076==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4076==    by 0x400622: main (in ./test)
==4076== 
Elemento 7 dentro del FOR de converción: 108
Elemento 8 dentro del FOR de converción: 105
==4076== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==4076==    at 0x4E88CC0: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1632)
==4076==    by 0x4E8F898: printf (printf.c:33)
==4076==    by 0x400B39: main (in ./test)
==4076== 
Base64: SSdtIGtpbGxp
==4076== 
==4076== HEAP SUMMARY:
==4076==     in use at exit: 33 bytes in 2 blocks
==4076==   total heap usage: 3 allocs, 1 frees, 1,057 bytes allocated
==4076== 
==4076== LEAK SUMMARY:
==4076==    definitely lost: 33 bytes in 2 blocks
==4076==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4076==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4076==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4076==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==4076== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==4076== 
==4076== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==4076== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==4076== ERROR SUMMARY: 31 errors from 10 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

La explicación detallada va para rato, la iré redactando para una segunda edición.

Primer error:

```
unsigned short int *boxOfNumbers = (unsigned short int*)malloc(decimalElements);
```

Debe ser:

```
unsigned short int *boxOfNumbers = (unsigned short int*)malloc(decimalElements * sizeof(unsigned short int));
```

En caso contrario te encontrarás con lecturas y escrituras fuera de la zona de memoria que has reservado.

Siguiente error:

```
printf("Elemento %d antes de converción a base64 : %d\n", i, boxOfNumbers[i]);
```

Debe ser:

```
printf("Elemento %hu antes de conversión a base64 : %hu\n", i, boxOfNumbers[i]);
```

O bien:

```
printf("Elemento %d antes de converción a base64 : %d\n", (int)i, (int)boxOfNumbers[i]);
```

Tras arreglar esos dos errores aún quedan tres sin resolver:

```
$ valgrind --leak-check=yes ./ejemplo1 49276d206b696c6c69
==5763== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==5763== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==5763== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==5763== Command: ./ejemplo1 49276d206b696c6c69
==5763== 
Elemento 0 antes de converción a base64 : 73
Elemento 1 antes de converción a base64 : 39
Elemento 2 antes de converción a base64 : 109
Elemento 3 antes de converción a base64 : 32
Elemento 4 antes de converción a base64 : 107
Elemento 5 antes de converción a base64 : 105
Elemento 6 antes de converción a base64 : 108
Elemento 7 antes de converción a base64 : 108
Elemento 8 antes de converción a base64 : 105
Elemento 0 dentro del FOR de converción: 73
Elemento 1 dentro del FOR de converción: 39
Elemento 2 dentro del FOR de converción: 109
Elemento 3 dentro del FOR de converción: 32
Elemento 4 dentro del FOR de converción: 107
Elemento 5 dentro del FOR de converción: 105
Elemento 6 dentro del FOR de converción: 108
Elemento 7 dentro del FOR de converción: 108
Elemento 8 dentro del FOR de converción: 105
==5763== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==5763==    at 0x4E88CC0: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1632)
==5763==    by 0x4E8F898: printf (printf.c:33)
==5763==    by 0x400B3C: main (ejemplo1.c:93)
==5763== 
Base64: SSdtIGtpbGxp
==5763== 
==5763== HEAP SUMMARY:
==5763==     in use at exit: 42 bytes in 2 blocks
==5763==   total heap usage: 3 allocs, 1 frees, 1,066 bytes allocated
==5763== 
==5763== 18 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 2
==5763==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5763==    by 0x400625: main (ejemplo1.c:19)
==5763== 
==5763== 24 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 2 of 2
==5763==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5763==    by 0x4006A7: main (ejemplo1.c:27)
==5763== 
==5763== LEAK SUMMARY:
==5763==    definitely lost: 42 bytes in 2 blocks
==5763==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5763==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5763==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5763==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5763== 
==5763== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==5763== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==5763== ERROR SUMMARY: 3 errors from 3 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Así que mirando el código veo que intentas mostrar una cadena que ha sido reservada y no inicializada (has tenido suerte que siempre use una zona que el octeto contiguo está a cero). Recuerda que una cadena de caracteres debe tener `n + 1` elementos, **el último debe ser el carácter `\0`**.

Así que he cambiado:

```
unsigned char *decimalConverted = (unsigned char*)malloc(base64Elements);
```

Por lo siguiente:

```
unsigned char *decimalConverted = (unsigned char*)malloc(base64Elements + 1);
memset(decimalConverted, 0, base64Elements);
```

Y con eso el error desaparece, pero aún quedan dos pérdidas de memoria (`memory leaks`) que se corrigen cambian el final del código de:

```
 printf("Base64: %s\n", (char*)decimalConverted);
 return 0;
```

A esto otro:

```
 printf("Base64: %s\n", (char*)decimalConverted);
 free(decimalConverted);
 free(boxOfNumbers);
 return 0;
```

Con lo que por fin tenemos una ejecución limpia de errores de memoria:

```
$ valgrind --leak-check=yes ./ejemplo1 49276d206b696c6c69
==6022== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==6022== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==6022== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==6022== Command: ./ejemplo1 49276d206b696c6c69
==6022== 
Elemento 0 antes de converción a base64 : 73
Elemento 1 antes de converción a base64 : 39
Elemento 2 antes de converción a base64 : 109
Elemento 3 antes de converción a base64 : 32
Elemento 4 antes de converción a base64 : 107
Elemento 5 antes de converción a base64 : 105
Elemento 6 antes de converción a base64 : 108
Elemento 7 antes de converción a base64 : 108
Elemento 8 antes de converción a base64 : 105
Elemento 0 dentro del FOR de converción: 73
Elemento 1 dentro del FOR de converción: 39
Elemento 2 dentro del FOR de converción: 109
Elemento 3 dentro del FOR de converción: 32
Elemento 4 dentro del FOR de converción: 107
Elemento 5 dentro del FOR de converción: 105
Elemento 6 dentro del FOR de converción: 108
Elemento 7 dentro del FOR de converción: 108
Elemento 8 dentro del FOR de converción: 105
Base64: SSdtIGtpbGxp
==6022== 
==6022== HEAP SUMMARY:
==6022==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6022==   total heap usage: 3 allocs, 3 frees, 1,067 bytes allocated
==6022== 
==6022== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==6022== 
==6022== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==6022== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Pero no significa que esté limpia de errores en la lógica.

Comment: Hice la modificación que me propones sobre el `printf()`. Pero me sigue pasando lo mismo. Si se declara al puntero como `int *dec_val` el lio ocurre en **dev_val[4]**, pero si de declara como `unsigned short int *dec_val` ocurre lo mismo pero en elemento **dec_val[23]** tratando de convertir esta cadena **49276d206b696c6c696e6720796f757220627261696e206c696b65206120706f69736f6e6f7573206d757368726f6f6d**

Comment: ¿Pero qué lío se produce? Si quieres convertir texto a base64 no lo estás haciendo de manera correcta, tu programa no hace esa tarea, pero si quieres que corrijamos ese fallo es otro tema diferente, pero el valor de `dec_val[4]` no está siendo modificado. No sé si es que no estás explicando bien lo que te ocurre o qué está pasando, pero no le veo sentido a lo que dices.

Comment: Por lio me refiero a que me altera el valor de los elementos. Aca dejor el código mejor codificado y mas legible supongo.

Comment: Lo miraré cuando tengo un rato libre, pero yo también uso Ubuntu 16.04 y a excepción de los modificadores `-std=c11 -Wextra` yo uso `-Wall -pedantic`. Luego probaré con `c11` aunque no creo que cambie nada.

Comment: Agregada nueva edición con la última modificación de la pregunta y el análisis de memoria, corregidos los fallos encontrados y conseguida una ejecución limpia.

Comment: Excelente trabajo @OscarGarcia, se soluciono el problema que estaba teniendo. Voy a estudiar con detalle sobre los temas que mencionas como `memory leaks` e inicialización de memoria `memset`, etc. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Debes ser cuidadoso con el tamaño y signo de los datos, especialmente en funciones que dependen de tu definición para trabajar con los parámetros (como `printf`). Te recomiendo usar la herramienta `valgrind` para detectar problemas de incoherencia de tamaño de datos, acceso a zonas fuera de la memoria reservada (aunque no genere un volcado de memoria o `core dump` por estar dentro de la zona de memoria asignada por el sistema operativo al programa), uso de zonas de memoria sin inicializar, cadenas de caracteres sin el carácter de finalización, etc... ¡Suerte con el programa!

Comment: Mil Gracias por el apoyo!

Answer (score 1):

El comportamiento que muestras **NO SE PUEDE REPRODUCIR**.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Después de las últimas ediciones de la pregunta, **SEGUIMOS IGUAL**:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La salida que indicas **no se muestra**. Y el `Elemento 8` muestra `105`.

Probado con `clang`: **MISMO RESULTADO**:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Es decir que te da bien, es el resultado que debería mostrarme a mi. Tendra algo que ver con el SO?. Que no se pueda reproducir no significa que este pasando mal la info. A mi me arroja los resultados que posteo compilando exactamente el mismo código. Utilizo MacOS

Comment: Mas que el SO, el compilador y el hardware. Probado en Ubuntu 16.11, 64bits, gcc 6.2.0, Intel I3

Comment: Si te fijas, el resultado `Base64: SSdtIGtpbG` que te da a tí no es el mismo.

Comment: @RamiroDuttoLuquez Seguimos igual. **No** se puede reproducir.

Comment: Claro, por eso decia que el resultado que te devuelve es el correcto y el que debería mostrarme a mi, sin embargo a mi me devuelve `Base64: SSdtIGtpbG`. Ahora me surgen dudas de porque sucede esto. Estuve leyendo y el comando gcc en  Mac OS esta linkeado a clang de xcode, podria llegar a ser eso.

Comment: Voy a montarme un live usb de Ubuntu LTS 16.04 para compilar. Tambien voy a probar compilar con gcc en una distro de xubuntu de 32 bits a ver que sucede.

Comment: @RamiroDuttoLuquez Probado con `clang 3.8.1-12ubuntu1` -> Mismo resultado.

Comment: comando de compilación: gcc -Wall -g limpio.c

Comment: Mismo resultado en ambos casos: `gcc -Wall -g -o test test.c` y `clang -Wall -g -o test test.c`.

Comment: @RamiroDuttoLuquez un último comentario: en mi sistema, `sizeof( unsigned short int ) == 2`, `sizeof( char ) == 1`, `sizeof( int ) == 4`, y `sizeof( unsigned char ) == 1`. Compara con los tamaños en tu equipo.

Comment: `sizeof(unsigned short int) = 2`, `sizeof (char) = 1`, 'sizeof int = 4` , `sizeof(unsigned char) = 1`. Son los mismos.

Comment: Hasta donde se, lo que te sucede **es imposible**. Lo acabo de compilar en C++, que es mas *puntilloso* con los tipos. Da un par de *warning*s, pero sobre las cadenas, que no son `const`. El resultado **es exactamente el mismo**.

Comment: Probaste con una cadena hexadecimal mas larga? `49276d206b696c6c696e6720796f757220627261696e206c696b65206120706f69736f6e6f7573206d757368726f6f6d`

Comment: Por supuesto que **no**. Estoy intentando reproducir tus resultado. Haz una última cosa: compila y ejecuta esto: `#include <stdio.h> int main( void ) { int x = 1; printf( "%c\n", *((char*)&x)==1?'L':'B'); return 0; }`. En mi sistema, la salida es la letra `L`. Si te sale `B`, aun podemos llegar a algo. Si te sale `L` igual que a mi, lo dejo.

Comment: Trauma agradezco tu colaboración. @OscarGarcia pudo dar con la tecla a los fallos. Problema resuelto.